# PHP : call a METHOD dynamically

Tags: php, dynamic-programming

methosHere is the call to a class I created :

```
Utils::search($idRole, $this->roles, 'getId');
```

in the Utils, search method :

```
public static function search ($needle, $haystack, $getter) {
    $found = false;
    $i = 0;

    while($i < count($haystack) || $found) {
        $object = $haystack[$i];

        if($object->$getter === $needle) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

The haystack is an array of Role objects. Here is a part of the Role class :

```
class Role
{
  private $id;
  private $nom;

  public function __construct($id = 0, $nom = null) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->nom = $nom;
  }

  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }
}
```

running the `$object->$getter` part I have an exception :

```
Undefined property: Role::$getId
```

I thought that was the way to call a property dynamically.. What do I do wrong ?

thank you

Comment: Since `getId` is a method, not a prop, you have to call it as method: `$object->$getter();`

Comment: missing parenthesis () :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ways:

The 1st element is the object, and the 2nd is the method.

```
call_user_func(array($object, $getter))
```

You can also do it without **call_user_func**:

```
$object->{$getter}();
```

Or:

```
$object->$getter();
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to call a class property which is in `private` scope.

You created a getter method for this property (`Role::getId()`). Now you have to call that method and not the property itself (which is private and can't be accessed outside the Role class instance which holds it).

So you have to use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$id = call_user_func(array($object, $getter));
```

Comment: `call_user_function` cannot help to access private method unless it called inside that object.

Comment: There is a public method `Role::getId()` which can be called by `call_user_func()`.